# Passing a parameter to javascript function via CSS Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

So, in short, I have a set of .li

```
<ul>
  <li class="lmit_1"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
  <li class="lmit_2"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
  <li class="lmit_3"><a href="#">Who we are</a></li>
  <li class="lmit_4"><a href="#">Whats new</a></li>
  <li class="lmit_5"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>    
</ul>
```

and my javascript (jQuery)

```
<script>
  $(".lmit_" + id).click(function () {
    alert(id);
  });
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is receive whatever number is at the end of the css class as a parameter (.lmit_3 for example would allow id = 3) and therefore alert(id) should lead to a popup with the number 3? I am new to both programming and javascript so my apologies if the answer is staring me in the face...

Comment: Why can't you give all of them a common class and make the `lmit_n` an `id`? There's little use to having unique classes.

Comment: @Blender: Or better, use a data attribute to carry the, um, data.

Answer (score 4):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sFwZj/1/

```
$('li').click(function () {
  alert($(this).attr('class').split('_')[1]);
});
```

In your code you use undeclared variable called `id`, so it should throw error `ReferenceError: id is not defined`, when you try `".lmit_" + id`.

And also I think you should use `id` not `class` for this, also as was mentioned probably it will be better if you will store number in something like `data-id` attribute, then you may get it by `$(this).data('id')`.

Comment: I tried your code

    <script>
    $(".lmit_1").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('class').split('_')[1]);
    });
    </script>

This worked, but not ".lmit_" +id

Comment: works, thanks heaps! Out of curiousity what was my code trying to do? or was it completely off the mark?

Comment: Completely off.. unless you had a function that actually passed in `id` as a parameter that you could use..  or if it was inside a loop.. but `id` didn't represent anything

Comment: .prop is supposedly better than attr

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li").click(function () {
  alert(this.className.split('_')[1]);
});
```

should do it

But why not

```
    <ul>
     <li class="lmit" id="lmit_1"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
     <li class="lmit" id="lmit_2><a href="#">About us</a></li>
```

with

```
$(".lmit").click(function () {
  alert(this.id.split('_')[1]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to store any data that you want to use in the data attribute. This way you are not relying on classes and ids too heavily (and string processing) as well as have some separation between formatting and functionality.

Your html will look like this:

```
 <ul>
<li class="lmit" data-myattr="1"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
<li class="lmit" data-myattr="2"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

note that data-myattr can be called anything with a "data-" prefix.

to access your data

```
       $(".lmit").click(function(){
//you can access it as an attribute
        alert($(this).attr("data-myattr"));
//or you can access it as data
           alert($(this).data("myattr"));
        })
```

or for even more classless solution use event delegation

```
$("ul").delegate("li", "click", function() {
 alert($(this).data("myattr"));
});
```

so you do not need lmit class at all in your html

```
 <ul>
<li data-myattr="1"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
<li data-myattr="2"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).prop('class').split('_')[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are all correct.  If you wanted to grab the item number in the `<ul>`, you have an alternative.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).index()+1);
});
```

The benefit is that you will not have to generate the class names (if that is all they are used for)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[li][class^="lmit_"]').click(function () {
  alert($(this).attr('class').split('_')[1]);
});
```

**if you use $('li') if u click on any li it does not have  "limit_" class also will be fired.**